# Shorten long SQL log entries in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am doing different queries like this:

```
Offer.where("id IN (?) AND foo = ?", offer_ids, 'bar')
```

where offer_ids was computed and has a length of about 1.000 ids.

These cause very long entries to the development.log like:

```
Offer Load (12.9ms)  SELECT `offers`.* FROM `offers` WHERE (id IN (156439476,162525730,169378363,197193532,209583012,212783238,236381946,260584008,267542041,140892256,154059101,157130091,158223924,161242255,161410617,169374703,184305303,187582050,234519939,235460328,252011721,253958427,257583669,260506433,262371001,262925076,265363980,266580943,268164854,271348458,272595168,272965063,141293866,162515580,195738185,210118609,210183244,210783954,212896682,219931290,224907551,225764370,227558502,234479337,234536939,236329414,238409428,241871979,245480324,245491111,245507734,253281480,254462074,257921737,265282309,265542934,266584572,267530034,268798204,271548316,272761011,272899348,273012205,119125136,134552742,166766466,169187658,213728958,213732981,225761919,234827176,247156634,247196151,247214973,247659810,259275332,261664338,262780711,267516898,267741935,270442768,271445586,271630463,272560287,272643405,272957626,106364954,205619149,213425974,213731373,243644164,266104747,266428301,266947751,268013142,126413832,157986541,175322047,204080600,205821543,205821564,205830753,205848558,207430869,207442535,207458847,207952331,208122137,213731142,217001805,226506891,228735112,243682190,257949941,265512977,265908636,268833366,269372138,270447643,271237573,59037247,59169923,662 ...) AND foo = 'bar')
```

I am actually interested in these log entries, but not the specific ids and scrolling through these long entries slows down my optimization.

Is there a gem or easy way to reduce the log the way that mysql slow query log does:

```
Offer Load (12.9ms)  SELECT `offers`.* FROM `offers` WHERE (id IN (?) AND foo = ?)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any way to change the log. However, if you are on the latest version of rails, you can use subqueries, which might be one way to prevent long lines of logging.

For example,

If you currently have:

```
offer_ids = @business.offers.map(&:id) # this is an array object
Offer.where("id IN (?) AND foo = ?", offer_ids, 'bar')
```

You can refactor your code to:

```
offer_ids = @business.offers # this is an ActiveRelation object
# offer_ids = @business.select(:id).offers # you can use this line instead of above line

Offer.where(:id => offer_ids, :foo => 'bar')
```

In this case, you will get a query like:

```
SELECT `offers`.* FROM `offers` WHERE (id IN (SELECT id FROM `offers` WHERE business_id = 4) AND foo = 'bar')
```

The difference is in whether you pass an `Array` object or an `ActiveRelation` object.

An `ActiveRelation` object is what you get when you use a query method like `where`, `select`, `limit` etc. that has not yet perform the query. In this case, be careful not to use methods like `count`, `maximum`, `all` or any other array methods (eg. `map`, `select`), which will force the query to run resulting in an `Array`.

Comment: This will surely help me with some queries. Some id computations I will have to do in ruby, but for the other ones, it's a great hint. Thank you!